# array_flip is not functioning properly

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array in PHP:

```
Array ( [0] => Email [1] => Email [2] => Email [3] => 
 Email [4] => Email [5] => Email [6] => Email [7] => Email )
```

when I try to flip it using array_flip, it returns only last one like `[Email] => 7`, However,it doesn't show rest of them. How can I fix it

Comment: Well if every single key actually points to the text "Email" then this would be expected, as it would set 'Email' => Key for each item, overwriting it each time since array keys must be unique...

Comment: You cannot have several *keys* all called `Email`. What would you expect the output to be?

Comment: From the manual: "If a value has several occurrences, the latest key will be used as its values, and all others will be lost."

Comment: Is there any other such as method which can give all result

Comment: How do you expect that result to look like?!

Comment: Yes, Now I understand, in this case I have to change the structure of script

Comment: Because, Currently, the system is supposed to important emails. so because it takes last one, I was wondering why it is taking only last one

Answer (score 4):

In PHP, the array cannot have duplicated keys. PHP will take the last key and discard the rest.

From the [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/array_flip) manual:

> If a value has several occurrences, the latest key will be used as its
>   values, and all others will be lost.